# Lucene.Net:search does not find all the values

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

Use Lucene.Net 3.0.3.
I have several classes with fields like this:

```
public class Test1
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

How i create index:

```
 var doc = new Document();
 doc.Add(new Field(KEYWORDS_FIELD_NAME, someUid, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

How i create Query:

```
var analyzer=new RussianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);

private Query ParseQuery(string queryString,Analyzer analyzer)
{
var classQuery = new BooleanQuery();
var hs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
foreach(var par in Parameters)
{ 
  classQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term(KEYWORDS_FIELD_NAME,par.ClassName.ToLower()),Occur.SHOULD); 
  hs.add(par.PropertyName);
}

var parser=new MultiFieldQueryParse(Version.LUCENE_30, hs.ToArray(), analyzer);
var multiQuery=parser.Parse(queryString.Ttim());
var result=new BooleanQuery
          {
            {classQuery,Occur.MUST},
            new BooleanClause(multiQuery,Occur.MUST) 
          };
  return result;
 }
```

And search request:

```
 var query=ParseQuery(queryString,analuzer);
 using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(luceneDirectory))
 {
       var hits = searcher.Search(query, null, 10000);
 }
```

In the search index there is a "Name" property of class Test1.
Some of the values of the properties are:

40002
   40001
   4001
   4009

and other similar values.

When I enter "4001", the search produces one result. That suits me.
However, when I enter "400", the search does not find any value.
I understand that this value is not in the index, but I expect that the search in this case will find "similar" values: 4001, 40002 and others.

Can this be done? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

P.S. it works with "400*" and MultiFieldQuery without RegexQuery. It slow per 30 percents.
When i use RegexQuery- 70-80 percents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try search for 400*, You would also need to [WildCardQuery](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/d1b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_wildcard_query.html)
Not a BooleanQuery